# Ajax Laravel Post Request to Controller Error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, routes

```
   <meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/> 

 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async: true,
      url: "/page",
      headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') },


      success: function(html) {
        $("#results").append(html);

    });
```

Routes.php

```
 Route::post('/page', function () {
    $cont = Content::orderby('pscore','DESC')->take(3)->get();           
  return View::make('content.moreContent')->with('cont',$cont);
```

});

This thing works for me but if i make Call to controller it throws error 
500 (Internal Server Error)

Controller

```
   public function more()
{
        $cont = Content::orderby('pscore','DESC')->take(3)->get();              
        return View::make('content.moreContent')->with('cont',$cont); 

}
```

Comment: `500 Server = Error in your Code/Controller` Can you please fix it ?

Comment: can you show us your controller and controller route implementation.

Comment: Check your laravel log file and can you copy the error code into here please. it is in the storage directory